# how to textview and android

Tags: android

I would like to create a dialog that contains a link for my site (on android), and would want the phone's browser to open when the user clicks on the link. I currently have:

```
@Override 
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id){
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MyActivity.this);                                                

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("MyTittle");
ImageView image = (ImageView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.image); 

image.setImageResource(R.drawable.launcher_icon);
TextView lblClickable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 
String htmlText = "Link to my <a HREF='http://www.rainbowbreeze.it'>site</a>"; 
 lblClickable.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));
//needed to enable click on the link     
lblClickable.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
return dialog; }
```

the above code fires NullPointerException in the line that contains `lblClickable.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));` any suggestions? What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `lblClickable` is null, this line is probably wrong:

```
TextView lblClickable = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

corrected:

```
TextView lblClickable = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
```